# Changing devise flash messages from notice to error

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know that you can override the default devise controllers and I did so for the Registrations and Sessions Controller. I know that you can also change the text for the flash messages in devise under locale. However, I am not sure how to change the type of flash message showing for the sessions controller when there is an invalid combination of username and password.

The create method looks like

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

I suspect that the validation is done during the follow call

```
warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

But this is where I am not sure how to overwrite that in my app.

Also, I think it is a complex override for such a simple use case of changing the color of a flash notice.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with custom failure app. As you can see this flash message is setting right [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v2.2.3/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L50) So you can change it in your custom failure app.

So at first you inherit your failure app from Devise's one:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def recall
    env["PATH_INFO"]  = attempted_path
    flash.now[:error] = i18n_message(:invalid)
    self.response = recall_app(warden_options[:recall]).call(env)
  end
end
```

place this file somewhere in your app and say Devise to use it like this (`config/initializers/devise.rb`):

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Nash! Worked out great!